# Listview adapter in a fragment giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, kotlin

I made a listview in a fragment
There is a null pointer exception for the adapter of the list view
But the Arraylist and the adapter are not null.

Error: lvElevator cannot be null

The error is for the below line

`lvElevator.adapter = EAdapter`

### Fragment Class

```
var EList=ArrayList<E1List>()

class EDetails: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        EList.add(E1List(1))
        EList.add(E1List(2))
        var EAdapter = EleAdapter(EList)
        lvElevator.adapter = EAdapter
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_elevators, container, false)

    }

    inner class EleAdapter : BaseAdapter {
        var EListAdapter = ArrayList<E1List>()

        constructor(EListAdapter: ArrayList<E1List>) : super() {
            this.EListAdapter = EListAdapter
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            var myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elevator_ticket, null)
            var myEle = EListAdapter[position]
            myView.tvEnum.text = myEle.elevatornum.toString()
            return myView
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return EListAdapter[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return EListAdapter.size
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to define lvElevator before fragment inflate the xml layout file.
There is two way to fix it.

**1)** Use **`onViewCreated()`** method instead to load data into views. And use onCreateView method to just inflate the view only.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    EList.add(E1List(1))
    EList.add(E1List(2))
    var EAdapter = EleAdapter(EList)
    lvElevator.adapter = EAdapter
}
```

**2)** Modify `onCreateView()` method like below.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    // Define views manually..
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_elevators, container, false)
    val lvElevator = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lvElevator)

    EList.add(E1List(1))
    EList.add(E1List(2))
    var EAdapter = EleAdapter(EList)
    lvElevator.adapter = EAdapter
    return view
}
```

As an experienced developer, I would recommended to use the first way as that method will only come in scope after layout completely inflated.